# timestamp discrepancy when using Cassandra CQL Poco object mapper

Tags: c#, cql, cassandra-2.0

here is my class

```
public class User
    {

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationTime { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my Cassandra schema

```
create table "Users" (
    username text primary key,
    registrationtime timestamp);
```

here is my mapping definition

```
 public class MyMappings : Mappings
{
    public MyMappings()
    {
        For<User>()
            .TableName("\"Users\"")
            .PartitionKey(u => u.Username);
    }
}
```

CQL mapper configuration:

```
MappingConfiguration.Global.Define<MyDataMappings>();
```

I can save and read a user object fine:

```
var user = new User() 
  {
    Username = "bob",
    RegistrationTime = DateTime.Now, 
  };

var userPrime = new Mapper(MyCluster.Instance.session).SingleOrDefault<User>("WHERE username = ?", user.Username);
```

Everything works as expected except the time difference in ResistrationTime for user and userPrime is around 6 hours. It has something to do with my local time being 6 hours away from the Universal Standard Time.

I do not get the same time that I saved. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamps in the database are always UTC. I recommend working with UTC times and only localizing when preparing to display them somewhere.

You could initialize 'user' using [DateTime.UtcNow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx)